# Coffeescript displaying an HTML form - get error "Shell for does not validate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

JSFiddle = http://jsfiddle.net/burtondav/Vke9u/

Coffeescript:

```
$('#calModal').modal('show')
$("savebtn").bind 'click', (event)  =>
  $("calModal").modal('hide')
  title = $(".modal-body #title").val()
  hours = $(".modal-body #hours").val()
  console.log title
  console.log hours
  return​
```

Getting:

```
{"error": "Shell form does not validate{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_lib', 'form':
    <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0x9703acc>, 'html_name': 'js_lib', 'label': u'Js 
    lib', 'field': <django.forms.models.ModelChoiceField object at 0x959a8ec>, 
    'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_lib'}"
}
```

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot submit html forms on JSFiddle, because there is no server to receive them.